# iPad - I need to put a split view inside a tab bar application

Tags: ipad, tabbar, uisplitview

Is there a way to add a split view in a tabbar application using only IB, without add the split view programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/62217-simplest-way-make-split-controller-tab-bar-controller.html

or

[UISplitViewController in a TabBar ( UITabBarController )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475139/uisplitviewcontroller-in-a-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller/2493161#2493161)

or

[SplitViewController_Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347688/splitviewcontroller-problem)