# SplitViewController_Problem

Tags: ipad

Can we implement split view controller in a normal view controller as in my application we are implementing a tab bar controller and we need to put this split view in some other view and not in window because i just need to know if we are not making a split view based application can we put split view controller in any separate view  but not in appdelegate(Window) If Yes please give me possibe solution...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this would work if you added it to a tab bar controller.  Just create all the files for the split view just like XCode sets up a split view project and add the split view controller as a TabBar item just as you would any other view controller.  I wouldn't recommend adding the the split view controller in any subview of a view controller in your tab bar as it will not to receive many useful lifecycle events.