# Add SplitViewController in Tabbar

Tags: ipad

I am looking for Add the SplitViewController in Tabbar & as per the tabbar item clicked the data of the tableview will be changed.

Is it possible to resize view of the splitviewcontroller So the window is visible ?

So Any one can suggest me on this issue .....

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this solution?

[UISplitViewController in a TabBar ( UITabBarController )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475139/uisplitviewcontroller-in-a-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller/2493161#2493161)