# UISplitView Orientation problem

Tags: ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I use a TabBarController that contains 1 splitViewController and a standard viewController.
Everything works fine except when I rotate the device.

On the SplitViewController when I rotate the device from Portrait to Landscape and Landscape to Portrait everything is ok.
When I move to the tabBar that contains the viewController, when I rotate the device in any direction, everything is also ok.

But if the last orientation of the splitView controller was landscape and from the ViewController I rotate the device to Portrait, when I go back to the SplitView Tab, I lost the popover button..
Everything is displayed well if I rotate the device.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default problem for cases when you use UISplitViewController inside UITabBarController. The catch is, the device rotation notifications are not received by the UISplitViewController, if it's inactive. You can find more details here:

[UISplitViewController in a TabBar ( UITabBarController )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475139/uisplitviewcontroller-in-a-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller)