# SplitViewController with TabbarController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am using the split View functionality in my app.I have to put tabbar in rootViewController.

But when I add controllers in tabbar and add them into split view it doesnt split.

It only shows detailViewController.

Here is the code in application did finish launching:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIViewController  *viewController2,*viewController3,*viewController4;
    rootViewController = [[[CategoryItemsList alloc] init] autorelease];
    viewController2 = [[[SearchList alloc] init] autorelease];
    viewController3 = [[[FavoritesList alloc] init] autorelease];

    viewController4 = [[[Information alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  rootViewController,viewController2,viewController3,viewController4, nil];

    splitDetail = [[splitDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"splitDetailView" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];

    splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    // splitViewController.tabBarItem = controller.tabBarItem;
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav, splitDetail, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate=splitDetail;
    rootViewController.splitView=splitDetail;
}
```

Comment: Please specify title like "Splitview with tabbar for iPad".

Comment: SplitView is the control which is only available in iPad

Comment: Nop, Check this link : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ecslidingviewcontroller--2 Nowadays it is also available on iPhone. Though It is custom control but it is split view.

Comment: Check this link It may helps you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475139/uisplitviewcontroller-in-a-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: @ShwetaThakar: Did you try out my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this links. I think this is what you are looking out for:

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/using-a-uisplitviewcontroller-to-create-a-master-detail-ipad-app-with-monotouch/

Once you add the split view then you just need to add the object of the SplitViewController to the TabBarController as one of the viewControllers

Hope this helps.