# Master Detail application

Tags: ios, xcode-template

Hi so what i want to do is add tabs to a msater detail application template. Can someone help me? I also want to make each of the tabs have a table view where you can add a new item.

Comment: Are you asking about iOS? Please tag your question properly. Xcode is an IDE used for OS X and iOS development.

Comment: yes i am talking about iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following answer with links:

Answer:
[SplitViewController with TabbarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680532/splitviewcontroller-with-tabbarcontroller)

Direct Links:

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/using-a-uisplitviewcontroller-to-create-a-master-detail-ipad-app-with-monotouch/

Comment: What i mean is just to add tabs to the template master detail application

Comment: did you mean something like this? http://www.noorselijster19.com/2011/03/ios/combine-tabbar-and-splitview/

Comment: no i want to have the table where i can press the + button and add an object in one of the tabs